# How do I group curves in 2-D plots with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, plot

[image]

In the above image, you can see that there are 4 curves. I have two techniques (black and red). I test them on two different experimental scenarios. So corresponding to each scenario, I get one red and black curve each. I want to point out that one set of black and red curve belong to one experimental scenario. Hope that clears it.  While I am familiar with plotting this curves in pgfplots using the given data, I can't figure how to group them as shown in the image. The plot was generated using matlab.

- How do I group curves in a given pgfplot?
- In your opinion, are there better ways on grouping curves in a plot?

Comment: By "grouping", do you mean the circles around the plots?

Comment: that is one way of looking at it. I have two techniques (black and red). I test them on two different experimental scenarios. So corresponding to each scenario, I get one red and black curve each. I want to point out that one set of black and red curve belong to one experimental scenario. Hope that clears it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since don't have your MWE, I will use two simple curves to illustrate the idea for group annotation. Here, `axis cs` for annotation is used, where two nodes are defined for `ellipse` and `pin annotation` respectively. The actual coordinates are supposed to be determined by the users according to their needs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}

\tikzstyle{every pin}=[->, fill=white,draw=black,font=\footnotesize]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+ [black]{x};
\addplot+ [blue, mark=square]{x+2};
\node[coordinate] (A) at (axis cs:-2,-1) {};                       % for ellipse
\node[coordinate,pin=above:{N=3, and K=4}] at (axis cs:-2,1.5){};  % for pin
\end{axis}
\draw[red] (A) ellipse (0.3 and 1);                                % draw ellipse
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make clear that some curves belong together you should consider using different colours and a appropriate legend, or you could use annotations in your plot.

Comment: With all respect, this is more appropriate as a comment than an answer.